# Link js file and its libraries in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am linking my Model.js file in html script tag and the libraries that the js file uses are also linked in the html src tags, but unfortunately when I load the page, the `Model.js` file throws errors. These errors are due to missing ammo.js and cannon.js files, but I am linking them in HTML page. So how do I make my Model.js read these tags?

index.html

```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.6.2/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/ammo.js"></script>
    <script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/cannon.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Model.js"></script>
```

For example, the js file has the starting line as :

```
const UI = BABYLON.GUI.AdvancedDynamicTexture.CreateFullscreenUI("UI");
```

and I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_getComponent' of null
    at Model.js:1
```

Comment: Can your share the code sample or the errors? Maybe there is something missing on which Modal.js is dependent.

Comment: It is dependent on cannon.js and ammo.js files. Because when i add the same js contents inside the html files, it works well.

Comment: Mitch, can you share codepen or jsbin link ?